# Using token only in POST and not in GET http request (Django DRF) + not caching

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token

I'm using authentification with Django (DRF), and it's working.
But, I would like to use the Token only with POST request and not GET requests.
Is it possible ?

My code :
Settings :

```
# REST API
"rest_framework",
"rest_framework.authtoken",
```

and :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        # "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
        # "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ),
}
```

If I add this line, or not, it's the same :

```
class BlaBlaViewSet(APIView):
    #permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

So, how can I do that in the "post" function and not in "put" function, please ?

And, how to disable caching requests please ?

Comment: Without trying the approach, would the [require_POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST) decorator help you?

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to use token in POST method, and not in GET. I've have already wrote this 2 functions, but the Token is active in both :(